# Select records all of whose records exist in another join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In the following book club example with associations:

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clubs
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end

class Club
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end

class Book
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clubs
end
```

given a specific club record:

```
club = Club.find(params[:id])
```

how can I find all the `users` in the club who have all books in array of books?

```
club.users.where_has_all_books(books)
```

Comment: What database do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL it can be done with a single query. (Maybe in MySQL too, I'm just not sure.)

So, some basic assumptions first. 3 tables: `clubs`, `users` and `books`, every table has `id` as a primary key. 3 join tables, `books_clubs`, `books_users`, `clubs_users`, each table contains pairs of ids (for `books_clubs` it will be [`book_id`, `club_id`]), and those pairs are unique within that table. Quite reasonable conditions IMO.

Building a query:

1. First, let's get ids of books from given club:

   ```
   SELECT book_id
   FROM books_clubs
   WHERE club_id = 1
   ORDER BY book_id
   ```
2. Then get users from given club, and group them by `user.id`:

   ```
   SELECT CU.user_id
   FROM clubs_users CU
     JOIN users U ON U.id = CU.user_id
     JOIN books_users BU ON BU.user_id = CU.user_id
   WHERE CU.club_id = 1
   GROUP BY CU.user_id
   ```
3. Join these two queries by adding `having` to 2nd query:

   ```
   HAVING array_agg(BU.book_id ORDER BY BU.book_id) @> ARRAY(##1##)
   ```

   where `##1##` is the 1st query.

   What's going on here: Function `array_agg` from the left part creates a sorted list (of `array` type) of `book_ids`. These are books of user. `ARRAY(##1##)` from the right part returns the sorted list of books of the club. And operator [@>](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html) checks if 1st array contains all elements of the 2nd (ie if user has all books of the club).
4. Since 1st query needs to be performed only once, it can be moved to `WITH` clause.

Your complete query:

```
WITH club_book_ids AS (
  SELECT book_id
  FROM books_clubs
  WHERE club_id = :club_id
  ORDER BY book_id
)
SELECT CU.user_id
FROM clubs_users CU
  JOIN users U ON U.id = CU.user_id
  JOIN books_users BU ON BU.user_id = CU.user_id
WHERE CU.club_id = :club_id
GROUP BY CU.user_id
HAVING array_agg(BU.book_id ORDER BY BU.book_id) @> ARRAY(SELECT * FROM club_book_ids);
```

It can be verified in this sandbox: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cdPtRfT2uSGp4DSDywST92/5

Wrap it to `find_by_sql` and that's it.

Some notes:

- ordering by `book_id` is not necessary; `@>` operator works with unordered arrays too. I just have a suspicion that comparison of ordered array is faster.
- `JOIN users U ON U.id = CU.user_id` in 2nd query is only necessary for fetching user properties; in case of fetching user ids only it can be removed

Comment: Thanks! I'll see how it performs. I would have to stop using sqlite in local environments but that's probably a good change either way.

Comment: I improved query by adding ```WITH``` clause

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work by grouping and counting.

```
club.users.joins(:books).where(books: { id: club.books.pluck(:id) }).group('users.id').having('count(*) = ?', club.books.count)
```

If anyone knows how to run the query without intermediate queries that would be great and I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a situation where you'd make two queries, one to get all the ids you need, the other select perform a WHERE IN.